# igraph install error. select.error 10038.

Tags: python-2.7, igraph, installation-package

I am trying to install `pip install python igraph`. It runs but ends up in the below error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDtS8.png)

How can i fix this installation. The error is same while using `setup.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setup.py` is trying to be clever and show a countdown from 10 seconds to zero in order to give you time to read an important message. Unfortunately the trick does not work on Windows; that's why you are getting this error message. Run `python setup.py install --no-wait` and the error should go away.

On the other hand, since you are compiling on Windows, you are probably better off with using the pre-compiled packages from [this page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-igraph) instead. Otherwise you would also need a working C compiler in order to get things done.

Comment: Installed with the pre-compiled packages as you mentioned. Runs now. Thanks a lot.